# ionic 2 beta 8 set root page wont navigate

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to set the root page depending on if the user is logged in or not. The app wont navigate to the page that I want. But if I change to another page, then it works. So i figured that something must be wrong with the page that I'm navigating to, but I can't seem to figure it out.

app.ts:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform, ionicBootstrap, Nav} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import {TabsPage} from './pages/tabs/tabs';
import {StartPage} from './pages/startPage/startPage';
import {LoadingScreen} from './pages/loadingScreen/loadingScreen';
import {AuthService} from './services/AuthService';

@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  queries: {
    nav: new ViewChild('content')
  }
})

export class MyApp {

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage: any;

  constructor(platform: Platform, private auth: AuthService) {

    this.rootPage = LoadingScreen;

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    this.initialize();
    });


  }

  initialize() {

      this.auth.loggedIn().then(isLoggedIn => {

          console.log(isLoggedIn);
          if (isLoggedIn) {

              //This works
              this.nav.setRoot(TabsPage);

          } else {

              //This doesn't work, but if I change the page to TabsPage it works
              this.nav.setRoot(StartPage);

          }

      });

  }
}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [AuthService], {
  backButtonText: 'Back'
})
```

StartPage.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {LoginPage}from '../loginPage/loginPage';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/startPage/startPage.html'
})

export class StartPage {


  constructor(private nav: NavController) {

  }

  login(){

    this.nav.push(LoginPage);

  }

}
```

StartPage.html:

```
<ion-content class="startPage" scroll="false">
  <div>
    <h1 class="startTitle">Flurn</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="button-bottom" bottom>
    <button class="button button-block button-light"  (click)="login()">
                Login
            </button>
    <button class="button button-block button-light" style="color:#019688;" disabled (click)="signup()">
                Signup
            </button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

I get no errors in the console in my webrowser ... What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I've created this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8hIcn6ckXvDi3o05dWVZ?p=preview) with your code (without the auth logic) and the StartPage (named `Page1` in the plunker) seems to be working fine.

The only difference between your `StartPage.ts` and my `page1.ts` are this page import:

```
import {LoginPage}from '../loginPage/loginPage';
```

and the `login()` method:

```
login(){
    this.nav.push(LoginPage);
}
```

What happens if you add a `debugger;` just before these lines of the code and follow the code debugging step by step (with f11 in chrome)?

```
//This doesn't work, but if I change the page to TabsPage it works
this.nav.setRoot(StartPage);
```